# Netacad - Cisco Plateform impossible to launch JNLP applications using “Java Web Start”

Tags: java, flash, browser, jnlp

I tried to open my chapter's exam or the test configuration for `Packet Tracer Online` but nothing is launched.

I have updated `Java` & `Adobe Flash Player` and my browsers.

My configuration:

- `Java 8` rev 131
- `Adobe Flash Player` 25
- `Packet Tracer` 6.3 & 7.0
- Firewall: `Comodo Firewall` 10 (I tried also uninstalled but same way)

(I activated the `Java`'s console and browser console):

Java console:

```
<https://pastebin.com/hfKLAdMP>
```

Browser console:

```
<https://pastebin.com/D0tWZBu3>
```

I tried it in `Google Chrome`, `Firefox`, `IE`, `Edge`:

- `Google Chrome`: Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)
- `Firefox`: 53.0.2 (32 bits)
- `Microsoft Edge`: 40.15063.0.0

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: 1) *"`https://pastebin.com/D0tWZBu3`"* Don't post relevant details at an external location! Instead [edit] the question & post the details here. 2) *"Anyone can help me ?"* [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Chrome does not run Java plugin.

Comment: I tested also on Firefox, IE, Edge & Opera :(